# Which hypothesis test would you choose for a test group and a control group, each of which has a measurement outcome at beginning and end of study

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have two groups, a test group and a control group. I need to make a number of observations (probably 2, but perhaps a greater number) on each group throughout the study. The level of measurement will be interval. I am interested in if a particular kind of training will improve the performance of the test group. Which hypothesis test do you think would be best in this scenario?

1. The **Independent samples t-test** seems appropriate in some ways but does not seem (to me) to account for the multiple observations required across time.
2. The **Paired t-test** also seems appropriate but assumes the samples are related; the test group and control group are not related.
3. The **anova** seems appropriate, but it seems to require that samples be unrelated; some of the samples in my dataset are related (e.g., the first control observation and the last control observation).
4. The **repeated-measures anova** seems appropriate but assumes that the groups are related. The test group and control group are not related.

How would I decide between these tests (or others) in this situation?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not any one hypothesis, but a generalized linear model (GLM).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, I think you shouldn't be looking into hypothesis tests, but in time series analysis.

(After edit of question) I think a paired t-test should be used. The two groups are "related" because they will fill in the same test, with the difference of one group not having training and the other group having had training. However I don't know if you should account for the fact that the groups containt different people.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Tibo! I reread my question, and you are right, that is how it sounded. I am testing whether a particular kind of training will improve the performance of my test group. If time series analysis can help with that, that would be great. But if not, I have clarified my question above. Thanks again.

Comment: So what you are trying to do is this: Give group 1 no training and group 2 training and compare if there's a difference in their performance? Will these groups consist out of the same people or not?

Comment: Exactly. Give one group no training and the second group training. The groups are not the same people. But I will take two measurements of both groups. Perhaps this is a single measurement? Perhaps the single measurement is just how much their performance degraded/improved over time?

Comment: Ok. Thanks, Tibo. I'll look into the last bit that you said you were unsure of. If you copy this last comment into the main answer box, I will mark it as the best answer for now. (I won't change it unless someone ends up correcting us later.) Thanks again!

Comment: This is neither time series analysis nor paired hypothesis testing. The appropriate technique is called difference in differences and has a Wikipedia page.